# How to validate form when only one out of two required fields is filled in

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I have a contact form.  It asks for your name and then it asks you whether you'd like to be contacted via telephone or email.  The telephone and email fields are hidden unless the user selects a radio button for telephone or email.  Once you click on either telephone or email I validate whether they input a correct telephone or email address.

My question is how to check with JQuery Validation and print out an error message if the user hasn't clicked on either radio button?

Comment: You're going to need to show something... I suggest the form's HTML and your jQuery from the `.validate()` function for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you simply asking how to validate a set of radio buttons?  Since you've shown no code, all I can show you is how you would validate a set of `radio` `input`'s with the plugin.

Then you would dynamically add/remove rules from the corresponding inputs using the [built-in `rules` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules).  Again, I'd need to see your code before customizing a solution.

**Working Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/PbHwX/

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            radiotest: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            radiotest: {
                required: "please select at least one option"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<input type="radio" name="radiotest" value="0" />
<input type="radio" name="radiotest" value="1" />
```

**Documentation**:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Answer (score 0):

**Update (2012-01-20 19:38)**:
I think I understood what you were looking for and noticed that you wanted to use jQuery's Validation plugin.

Here is a [working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KCXSL/) on JSFiddle *(Note: I forked from Sparky's fiddle)*

By default, only the rule regarding the radio buttons is set. All the messages are set in advance, and the specific fields of the form are hidden. Now whenever a radio button is clicked, I hide the useless field, remove the corresponding rule. I also show the right field and add the corresponding rule.

The specific piece of code you were looking for must be something like:

```
    /* Toggle fields */
    $('#mailfields').hide();
    $('#phonefields').show();

    /* Remove email rule */
    $('input:text[name=emailadress]').rules('remove');

    /* Add a requirement rule for phone */
    $('input:text[name=phonenumber]').rules('add', { required: true });
```

---

**First answer:** You say that when the user select one of the two radios (email or telephone), you display one or the other corresponding field. Therefore, I assume that you already have some jQuery code which runs every time the user clicks on one radio button.

This code could add a class or a hidden field or whatever you prefer (or whatever is the best common practice for this case, I am unfortunately not experienced enough to know that...) which let you know later that the user did select an option.

If you can show more of the code (a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for instance) I could give you a more specific answer. Still, here is what I would do:

1. Have all fields of the form already in the HTML document
2. Hide/Display fields as you want with jQuery and CSS
3. The test is always the same:

   ```
   (phoneRadio.selected && phoneField.filled)
   || (mailRadio.selected && mailField.filled)
   ```

Let me know how that helps.

Comment: ok I pasted my validation code here: http://jsfiddle.net/LyVRS/.  My question is how do you add logic into the `validate` function.  I wanna do something like `if(!email && !telephone) {print error}`.

Comment: @mikeglaz, please add your code to your original posting so that everyone can see it, and so that the question remains useful after the link goes dead.  Also, where your HTML?

Answer (score -1):

you can use jquery unobtrusive if you are many form and use ASP.NET MVC etc..
or you can do something like this :

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/OlivierAlbertini/9ma3u/)

```
$('#form').click(function (e) { // or $form.submit handler
    if ($('#email').val() == "") // or you can use an regex validation
    {
       e.preventDefault();
        // set message here
        $('#message').css('color', 'red').append('email invalid !');
    }
});

$('form').submit(function (e) {
    alert('submited :' + $('#email').val());
});
```

Comment: Where did the OP say he was using ASP.NET MVC etc?  Because, he's certainly not going to need to use `unobtrusive.js` otherwise.

Comment: You're only supposed to post _relevant answers_ here, not hypothetical scenarios.  [Your jsFiddle Demo is also broken](http://jsfiddle.net/OlivierAlbertini/9ma3u/)... it's set for `Mootools`, contains no `radio` inputs, includes no plugins, and therefore does nothing at all.

Comment: Excuse me to try to help someone, but... Indeed your response is better :). Peace man

Comment: Don't take these comments personally.  All the guidelines are meant to keep the site filled with high quality content, which is more helpful to more people.