# How to validate fields tied to radio buttons?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a contact form which requires a name, method of contact (email or telephone), an email or telephone text-field(depending on which radio button is clicked) and a description.  I'm validating with jQuery's Validation plug in.  The email field appears when one clicks on the email radio button and the same for the telephone field.  My question is how would the code look to validate the email text-field when the email radio button is clicked and validate the telephone text-field when the telephone radio button is clicked.  One of them should be required but not both.  If it helps, when I click on the email radio button the email text-field appears and the telephone text-field disappears and vice-versa.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="contact_name">Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input id="contact_name" name="contact[name]" size="30" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="How_would_you_like_to_be_contacted_">How would you like to be contacted?</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="radio">
        <input id="contact_type_email" name="contact_type" type="radio" value="email" />
        <label for="Email">Email</label>
      </label>

      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

      <label class="radio">
        <input id="contact_type_telephone" name="contact_type" type="radio" value="telephone" />
        <label for="Telephone">Telephone</label>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group" id="email">
    <label class="control-label" for="contact_email">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input id="contact_email" name="contact[email]" size="30" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group" id="telephone">
    <label class="control-label" for="contact_telephone">Telephone</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input id="contact_telephone" name="contact[telephone]" placeholder="###-###-####" size="30" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#email').hide();
  $('#telephone').hide();

  var email = false;
  var telephone = false;

  $('#contact_type_email').click(function() {
    $('#email').show();
    $('#telephone').hide();

    email = true;
    telephone = false;
  });
  $('#contact_type_telephone').click(function() {
    $('#telephone').show();
    $('#email').hide();

    telephone = true;
    email = false;
  });

  jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");
    return this.optional(element) ||
        phone_number.match(/^[2-9]\d{2}-[2-9]\d{2}-\d{4}$/);
  }, "Please specify a valid phone number");

  $('#new_contact').validate({
    ignore: ":hidden",
    rules: {
      'contact[name]': {
        required: true
      },
      'contact[email]': {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      'contact[telephone]': {
        required: true,
        phoneUS: true
      },
      'contact[description]': {
        required: true
      },
      contact_type: {
        required: true
      }
    },

    messages: {
      'contact[name]': {
        required: "Please provide a name."
      },
      'contact[telephone]': {
        required: "Please provide a valid telephone number."
      },
      'contact[description]': {
        required: "Please provide a description of the work you would like done."
      }
    },

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      error.appendTo("#error");
    }

  });
});
```

I tried doing something with the vars `email` and `telephone` but not sure if they're needed.

Comment: I tried helping you [here with a very similar question about the same plugin and never heard anything](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427062/how-to-validate-form-when-only-one-out-of-two-required-fields-is-filled-in).  Like my comment over there, please show your HTML and jQuery.

Comment: I'm sorry, my head is in the clouds.

Comment: I believe I solved your issue below.  You only need to integrate it with your show/hide code.

Comment: I added a "proof-of-concept" jsFiddle to my answer below.  You'll only need to tweak it to make it pretty.  http://jsfiddle.net/7622M/

Comment: Thanks @sparky, I really really appreciate your help.  There is one issue that's left.  The validation is in real time except for the radio buttons.  If I click submit with the email radio checked I get the error message "Please provide a valid email address."  But if I click on the telephone radio the message doesn't switch to "Please provide a valid telephone number." unless I hit the submit button.

Comment: The second jsFiddle I provided already takes care of all that.  I don't see any messages left over after changing the radio button... http://jsfiddle.net/7622M/ ~ If you're expecting the message to morph from one into the other... how can that happen, it's two different fields each with their own validation and message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As per documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), you'd use the [`depends` option under `rules`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).

```
rules: {
    telephone_field: {
        required: {
            depends:  function(element) {
                return $("#telephone_checkbox").prop("checked");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following demo is as close as I'm willing to get without seeing your specific code.  It's merely a demonstration about how to properly use `depends` with your scenario.  There is also no code included to make fields show/hide because, presumably, you already have some working code in that regard.

Nothing is `required` until a choice is made via the `radio` buttons.  Then only the field corresponding to it's "checked" `radio` button is made `required`.  (The `required` rule is toggled along with the `radio` buttons thanks to `depends`.)

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZqHMq/**

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            telephonefield: {
                required: {
                    depends: function (element) {
                        return $("#telephone").prop("checked");
                    }
                }
            },
            emailfield: {
                required: {
                    depends: function (element) {
                        return $("#email").prop("checked");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    telephone: <input type="text" name="telephonefield" />
    <br/>
    email: <input type="text" name="emailfield" />
    <br/>
    telephone: <input type="radio" name="contactradio" id="telephone" />
    <br/>
    email: <input type="radio" name="contactradio" id="email" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

---

**EDIT:**

This is a crude "proof-of-concept" demonstration using your show/hide code:  http://jsfiddle.net/7622M/