# jQuery validate on radio button click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I have a contact form which asks whether one would like to be contacted via email or telephone.  When you click on the email radio button, an email text-field appears.  Same for clicking the telephone radio button.  When I click on the email radio button for example and enter an invalid email, the invalid email error message appears on blur.  Now when I click on telephone, the telephone text-field appears but the invalid email error message does not disappear.  That's what I would like to happen.

**HTML (with Bootstrap)**

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="How_would_you_like_to_be_contacted_">How would you like to be contacted?</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <label class="radio">
      <input id="contact_type_email" name="contact_type" type="radio" value="email" />
      <label for="Email">Email</label>
    </label>

    <label class="radio">
      <input id="contact_type_telephone" name="contact_type" type="radio" value="telephone" />
      <label for="Telephone">Telephone</label>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group" id="email">
  <label class="control-label" for="contact_email">Email</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="contact_email" name="contact[email]" size="30" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group" id="telephone">
  <label class="control-label" for="contact_telephone">Telephone</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="contact_telephone" name="contact[telephone]" placeholder="###-###-####" size="30" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#email').hide();
  $('#telephone').hide();

  $('#contact_type_email').click(function() {
    $('#email').show();
    $('#telephone').hide();
    $('#contact_telephone').val('');
  });

  $('#contact_type_telephone').click(function() {
    $('#telephone').show();
    $('#email').hide();
    $('#contact_email').val('');
  });

  $('#new_contact').validate({
    rules: {
      'contact[name]': {
        required: true
      },
      'contact[email]': {
        required: {
          depends: function(element){
            return $("#contact_type_email").prop("checked");
          }
        },
        email: true
      },
      'contact[telephone]': {
        required: {
          depends: function(element) {
            return $("#contact_type_telephone").prop("checked");
          }
        },
        phoneUS: true
      }
    }
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      error.appendTo("#error");
}
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you see the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kqczf/13/)? Also, by default, the error message is placed next to the `input`. The container containing both the `input` and error message should be hidden when you choose a different radio button.

Comment: no, that won't work.  I have errorPlacement placing all my errors in an #error div at the top of the form.

Comment: Ah, ok that makes more sense. Your code is missing some semicolons/ending parenthesis. Are those copy/paste errors?

Comment: How is this question any different than [what you already asked here where you never responded to my attempted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528505/how-to-validate-fields-tied-to-radio-buttons)?  [How to validate fields tied to radio buttons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528505/how-to-validate-fields-tied-to-radio-buttons)

Comment: @Sparky: I think this one is slightly different as it deals with problems with `errorPlacement`. Is that accurate? If not I'll vote to close as well.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker, The other one was also about how and where to place & remove the error.  The last edit on [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14529239/594235) dealt with removing the obsolete error message which is what he's asking about here.

Comment: @Sparky: Agreed, voting to close...

Comment: @Sparky, I did use your code from your previous answer to my question.  I thanked you in the comments.  I apologize, but I forgot the check the answer as satisfactory, which I just did now.  I used your previous code and it worked great.  But this is a different issue.

Comment: @Sparky, my initial question was how to turn validation on a text-field once the corresponding radio button is clicked.  This deals with turning off validation once the opposite button is clicked.

Comment: @mikeglaz, there is no way to "turn off" validation.  You would make the `required` rule `depend` on the `radio` button and remove the obsolete error message on the `radio` click, which is exactly what I had shown in last edit of my previous answer.  Please construct a jsFiddle showing exactly what you have working now and clearly explain what it still needs to do.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sparky, here's my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mikeglaz/BmNWR/ When I click on the email radio button, enter an invalid email address, then click on the telephone radio button, my invalid email error message is still there.

Comment: I fixed it by adding `$('label.error').hide();`, same thing I did in the demo I included [in the last part of my last answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14529239/594235).  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/BmNWR/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From OP's comments:

> @Sparky, here's my jsFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/mikeglaz/BmNWR](http://jsfiddle.net/mikeglaz/BmNWR). When I click
>   on the email radio button, enter an invalid email address, then click
>   on the telephone radio button, my invalid email error message is still
>   there. – mikeglaz

This is what I tried to show you in [the last edit of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14529239/594235) on your previous question.

I cleaned up your logic a bit and added `$('label').hide();`...

```
$('#contact_type_email').click(function () {
    $('#email').show();
    $('#telephone').hide();
    $('#contact_telephone').val('');             // <-- fixed this
    $('label[for="contact_telephone"]').hide();  // <-- added this
});

$('#contact_type_telephone').click(function () {
    $('#telephone').show();
    $('#email').hide();
    $('#contact_email').val('');
    $('label[for="contact_email"]').hide();      // <-- added this
});
```

**Modified jsFiddle Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/BmNWR/8/**

Comment: I know, I saw this in your previous post.  But what I want is only to hide the telephone or email error and have all other errors still show.

Comment: @mikeglaz, For this, it's just a very simply matter of tweaking the jQuery selector to target each specific `label` instead of all error labels.  See updated code in answer... I think we finally got it sorted out.

Comment: @mikeglaz, waiting for your confirmation.

Comment: Sorry, very busy with work and school.  But yes, that's exactly what I wanted. I really appreciate your help @Sparky. One question though, how does `label[for="contact_email"]` for example know which label to associate with if I don't have any label tags in my HTML?

Comment: @mikeglaz, Those `label` elements are the ones created by the plugin.  You can see them in your DOM inspector.

Comment: I'm very grateful for all your help @Sparky.